# GNOME terminal launches into specific directory

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, configuration, gnome

I'm on Linux Mint 20, and somehow I've managed to make **GNOME terminal always launch into a specific directory** (it cds into my usual working directory). While it seemed like a good idea at the time, I've regretted it sincerely since. The problem is, **I can't figure out how to revert it**.

- The profile does not contain any launch commands
- My .bashrc doesn't contain anything
- My .profile doesn't contain anything
- I can't find anything related in my ~/.config dir
- I've rummaged around in /usr with no luck
- I've grepped forever, but the only thing similar I've found is in my .bash_aliases:
  `alias www=cd /media/daniel/Webdev/html`

This occurs both when I launch the terminal from cinnamon's menu, from cairo-dock, from another terminal or when I right-click and select "open in terminal".

Can anyone tell this dumb dumb where he screwed up? I'd be super grateful for any tips.

Thank you for your time!

Edit:

Here's the content of my ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Please have a look at the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` . ..... That's usually the file to edit.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Hi Knud, thanks for the suggestion! I've updated my question with the content of that file, but it doesn't look related.

Comment: To figure out whether this is related to the GNOME Terminal UI preferences, or just to the underlying shell itself: you may open `gnome-terminal`, go to the root of your homedir (`cd ~/`) and run a "nested shell" with trace mode on (`bash --login -i -x`). If at this point you end in a different directory, this is certainly due to a mere `cd` command (printed in the trace so obtained). Otherwise I'd suggest to locate the `gnome-terminal` launcher (by running `locate org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` or so) and inspect that file.

Comment: @ErikMD Fantastic reply. Thank you for your time. I wish you'd have posted that as an answer so I could have accepted it. I have no idea which of the million things I've tried fixed it, but after a reboot it seems to have been solved. I feel so silly. Your comment certainly led me in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ErnestMelville glad that you figured out how to address this issue! posted my suggestions as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, posting the hints I had suggested in the comments:

- To figure out whether this is related to the GNOME Terminal UI preferences, or just to the underlying shell itself:
  you may open `gnome-terminal`, go to the root of your homedir (`cd ~/`) and run a "nested shell" with trace mode on (`bash --login -i -x`).
- If at this point you end in a different directory, this is certainly due to a mere `cd` command (printed in the trace so obtained).
- Otherwise I'd suggest to locate the `gnome-terminal` launcher (by running `locate org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` or so) and inspect that file:
- In particular, there seems to be a relevant `Path=` key in [the freedesktop.org spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys).